# Regex - Allow alphanumeric, comma, period and space using PHP

Tags: php, regex

I found many places where question like this are solved but I have no idea why is it not working for me.

```
$reg = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9,. ]*$/'; // regex to allow only alphanumeric, comma, period and space
$count = preg_match($reg, $arr[1], $matches); // verify regex
if($count > 0){
    $objArray[] = array($arr[0] => $arr[1]); // if regex allowed create Object array
}
else{
    //error code
}
```

Alphanumeric works fine but does not allow comma and space while period are allowed.

Comment: `'/^[a-zA-Z0-9,\.\s]*$/'` try  it.

Comment: @AmitGarg No luck! The same thing is happening. And I don't think periods need to be escaped but anyway periods are allowed by this but not comma and space.

Comment: Could you give an example of which string is not correctly matched?

Comment: I have tested `'/^[a-zA-Z0-9,. ]*$/'` and it is working fine.

Comment: I think there may be some invisible char like `\n` in your string.

Comment: @AmitGargyou you don't need to escape the quantifier `.` in that situation.

Comment: @Jack Anything which has space or comma in between. eg "xx yy" and "xx,yy" won't work but "xx.yy" does work.

Comment: That makes no sense; see [this example](http://3v4l.org/nAC7d).

Comment: @AmitGarg No I am entering the data myself in fields. I dumped the variable before matching and there are nothing more than what I entered.

Comment: @AmitGarg: You were right. Not all but some string had special characters because I was url parsing the value and they were serialized. So the period remained period but comma became %2 and space became +.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the issue isn't the `^`, `*`, and `$` at the end? Your character class is correct, but what you're matching is "beginning of line, then 0 or more of `[a-zA-Z0-9,. ]`, then the end of the line".

What this means is that it'll match if there's nothing in the string (0 or more of your characters), but not if there is anything other than those characters (because it's anchored to the beginning and end of the line). If that's really what you want to know (if there is anything other than those characters), then you can reverse the character class like this, and remove the `^`, `*`, and `$`: `[^a-zA-Z0-9,. ]`.

Otherwise (if you want to know if the string has any of those characters), you should just remove everything but the character class: `'/[a-zA-Z0-9,. ]/'`.

Comment: `[^a-zA-Z0-9,. ]` doesn't even allow words. I think I will need `^`, `*` and `$`

Comment: Well, putting the `^` in reverses it, so you would then do `$count == 0`. I see from your comment above that that wasn't your problem though.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('/^[\w\s ,.]+$/', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
    # Matched text = $result[0][$i];
}
```

Comment: `\w` also matches underscore and you don't need `preg_match_all()` here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following expression

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\d ,.]*$
```

Comment: This is allowing everything including special characters. And 0-9 and \d are the same thing.

Comment: try using this instead [^,.a-zA-Z0-9]*$

Comment: Still allowing everything.